# tcp/ssh forwarding: laptop <-> cloud server <-> home server

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have the configuration as follows. At my home computer I launch jupyter notebook on port 7000 and set up reverse ssh to my cloud server

```
ssh -f -N -R 9000:localhost:7000 cloud_user@cloud.hosting.com
```

I want to access jupyter from my laptop by

```
http://cloud.hosting.com:9000
```

But connection refused. Nevertheless, I can do (from the cloud server console)

```
wget localhost:9000
```

and it is working. And also: if I ran jupyter on the cloud server (say on port 1234) then http://cloud.hosting.com:1234 is working. What I have to do for accessing home jupyter from the laptop?

Comment: I think your cloud server firewall is getting in the way. What firewall do you use?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really know. All settings are default (Ubuntu 16.04). If I run jupyter on the cloud server then I can access to it from the laptop

Answer (score 1):

You need "-g" on that ssh command.  "netstat -plnt | grep :9000" (on the cloud host) will show you the difference between your current command and the same with "-g".